# Unable to access my own webpage, ERROR: "Failed to load resource"

Tags: html

I recently registered a domain and have been working at a rough draft of a website, but now when I got the site up and running I am unable to load it, it worked initially and then it stopped working and then came back and now I have been unable to use it on my home computer since.

It works fine on my work laptop, for the moment at least, so I think it's something localized.

I have tried clearing cache in Google Chrome, tried it in MS Edge, flushed DNS settings as I thought my tampering with those might've caused something but the issue persists.

Greatly appreciate any help I can get.
The domain in question is solution.camp and when I go to the URL I get 1 of 2 errors in the source code, one of them simply says "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"

the other says: "GET http://solution.camp/ 404 (Not Found)"

I'm not sure if it can cause any problems but I followed their guide to force users to access the website via HTTPS, the code in that file is as follows:

```
#Rewrite everything to https
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Anyway, hope I put it clear enough, thank you!

Comment: This looks like a [DNS problem](https://www.computerworld.com/article/2545365/networking-fix-your-dns-problems.html)

Comment: Your website is running fine on https. And I don't see any error on the browser's console. Are you trying to load a page other than the index ?

Comment: I tried pinging it now @peprumo and it worked and now I can see the index page again but the page for Technology (technology.html) is blank instead.

I had issues on both the existing pages earlier, currently I can access the Index page again but not the Technology page.

Comment: When I get a blank page it's usually an iframe that seems to be bugging out, I do not know why I get the iframe pages as I have not used that tag in any of my code

Comment: @peprumo Furthermore I checked through the guide you provided but I can't see any of these steps applying that I haven't already tried unfortunately, I thought it was DNS issues as well hence why I tampered with them on my registrar, do you have any tips of something I can look at there? Thank you for the help so far